# OpenLDAP: Deleted user is still listed in the group

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

I'm currently doing openldap via command line. I added user **John** and added group **devgroup**, and I assigned **John** into **devgroup** group.
When I deleted a user(**John**) via command line

```
ldapdelete -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local" 
"uid=john,dc=example,dc=local"
```

The user is gone but not in previously assigned group member (**devgroup**). Is this a common behavior of openldap or am I missing something here?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
There is no link between the user and the group's user(basically I can add any nonexistence users into the group) hence it is not getting deleted. Is there any command to add a user to be linked with the group?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Update my post. Is it still okay to post here?

Comment: @jww Your comment is very nice! So should the whole SE work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already recognized group entries and their member entries are just that: Separate entries without hard linkage.

You have two options:

1. Implement your own script to remove a member entry and remove its DN from attribute *member* in the group entry.
2. Use OpenLDAP overlay [slapo-refint](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-refint) to let *slapd* remove the member reference from the group entry in case you delete the member entry.